# Copy and paste with single command/key with tmux

Tags: tmux

I really like the tmux-copycat plugin for selecting filenames in the terminal buffer, but one thing that would make it even better is the ability to copy and paste the selected text with one command (preferably bound to a key).

I'm not aware of any existing command to do this, so I imagine some trickery is needed. Any tips on where to get started on a solution?

Answer (score 1):

There is a pair of `tmux` commands that will do what you want. You'll want to bind them to a new shortcut (probably a prefix-key-command).

Let's say you are currently in copy mode and you've selected some text. Go to the command line (usually with prefix-`:`) and enter:

```
send-keys -X copy-selection-and-cancel ; paste-buffer
```

That will do exactly what it says: put the selection in a paste buffer, cancel copy mode, and paste the paste-buffer contents to the shell command line (or wherever you were when you entered copy-mode).

So now you can bind those commands to key of your choosing with something like this in your tmux.conf file

```
bind-key X send-keys -X copy-selection-and-cancel \; paste-buffer
```

The only difference between this and running it directly is the need to escape the `;`. Hit that bound key next time you've selected some text in copy-mode and you've got your all-in-one copy-and-paste shortcut.

You might want to tune this a bit. For instance, you can use the `-t target-page` option to `paste-buffer` to paste to somewhere other than the current pane. Look at docs for the two commands in the `tmux` man page for ideas.

Comment: Looks good, although I'm running an older (and somewhat customized) build of tmux that doesn't support the -X option. No doubt I'll award you the answer once I've managed to update and test.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbach Sure. I'm not sure what version `-X` was added but it's been a while...since at least March 2013. If you can do so upgrading will be well worth it (features, stability, bug fixes).